# The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request Error on RS-232 using ModBus

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, serial-port, modbus, tcomport

I am facing a critical problem while reading data from COM-PORT using RS 232 Cable in C#, Error is

> The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request

Its quite a common error and i search it on google , people talked about it that its a Microsoft bug, but i couldn't get any fix to this. need your help.

Comment: Where does it throw, on what line, is it on a readline or something similar? Note : There is a lack of information here

Comment: i get the sample project from this address https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20929/Simple-Modbus-Protocol-in-C-NET

Comment: And the error is in GetResponse() function in modbus.cs class in line response[i] = (byte)(sp.ReadByte());